# Feature Layer is not showing the points on the map

Tags: c#, feature-layer, wpf, arcgis-api-wpf, maptips

I have a simple feature layer. The points will show up if I put the URL in a DynamicMapServiceLayer, but I need to use maptips, so that will not work. Below is my relevant XAML.

```
<esri:Map x:Name="MyMap" Background="#FFE3E3E3" WrapAround="True" MouseClick="MyMap_MouseClick" MouseRightButtonDown="MyMap_MouseRightButtonDown" Extent="-9834972.92753924,4441899.425293319,-9833977.88119163, 4442762.485358352">
                <esri:Map.Layers>

                    <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="MyLayer" Url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer" />
                    <!--<esri:ArcGISLocalDynamicMapServiceLayer ID="Calvert_City" Path="C:\Users\jessical\Documents\ArcGIS\CalvertCity_Test.mpk"/>-->
                    <!--<esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer  ID="Calvert_City" Url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_2/MapServer">

                </esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer>-->
                    <esri:FeatureLayer ID="Calvert_City" Url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_2/MapServer" Renderer="{StaticResource MySimpleRenderer}">

                        <esri:FeatureLayer.MapTip>
                            <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0,0,15,15" Background="{StaticResource PanelGradient}">
                                <StackPanel Margin="7">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Content" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"  />
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </esri:FeatureLayer.MapTip>
                    </esri:FeatureLayer>
                </esri:Map.Layers>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With featureLayers I think you need to reference a single layer in a map service or feature service.  So, instead of:

```
http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_2/MapServer
```

try

```
http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_2/MapServer/0
```

change the "0" at the end to match the layer you are interested in.